# Cannot get custom javascript to execute on page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, headers

I have a simple piece of "hello world" code I'm trying to execute on a page. I'm adding it using a PHP snippet:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">

jQuery(document).ready(() => {
  jQuery('div#tm-extra-product-options').click(() => {
    console.log("it's working!")
  });
});
</script>
<?php } );
```

I can get it to show up in the page source and if I paste that directly into the console it works fine, however when I load the page and try it, I get nothing. I know that jQuery is loading because it is defined in the console without my intervention (previously this was not the case), however the code itself appears to not work at all.

Comment: did you open the browser inspector to see if there is any console error?

Comment: Are you clicking on `div#tm-extra-product-options`? Are you certain that it's the correct selector?

Comment: I checked the console, no errors. The thing is I can paste the code into the console and it will work fine, outputting "it's working!" to the console everytime I click the element. It just won't work initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
add_action ( 'wp_head', 'custom_script_hook');
function custom_script_hook() {

?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php 

    $output='<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(() => {
          $("div#tm-extra-product-options").click(() => {
            console.log("it working!")
          });
        });
        </script>';
    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: This looks like it's working. Any idea why? is it because I'm outputting it through the use of echo?

Comment: Yes. It is the working use of the echo treated like a variable.

Comment: Are there any issues because the src is defined in one set of <script> tags, yet the code itself is in another set of <script> tags? Should I combine them into one set of tags in the $output block?

Comment: No, it just separation of the script. You can merge both script tags inside the single variable.

Answer (score -1):

It is always an headache working with jQuery in Wordpress.
Just try replace second jQuery with $ sign. 
I guess once you opened jQuery tag you need to continue with $ sign inside:
Like this

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">

jQuery(document).ready(() => {
  $('div#tm-extra-product-options').click(() => {
    console.log("it's working!")
  });
});
</script>
<?php } );
```